# Audioplayer start/stop with actionEvent

Tags: java, swing, actionevent, audio-player

I am have made a custom window with two JButtons which when clicked will start respectively stop a .wav playing. The trouble I have is that I can start the sound, but I can't stop it unless I close the program.

Clicking the start-button multiple times will make the same file play in "canon". I suspect this has to do with each button creating their own "instances" of the file, with them being within different {}, but I cannot find any way to solve this. I am open to changing / and or removing the methods I am currently using in favour for something which will work better.

Here is the code:

```
package jojo;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

import sun.audio.AudioPlayer;
import sun.audio.AudioStream;


public class Ljudknappar extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -389308630436200228L;

    private JButton knapp;
    private JButton knapp2;




    public Ljudknappar()
    {
        super("Ett fönster");
        super.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 

        super.setLocation(50,50);


        super.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400,400));
        super.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
        knapp = new JButton("Starta");
        knapp.addActionListener(this);
        knapp.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(90,30));
        add(knapp);

        knapp2 = new JButton("Stopp");
        knapp2.addActionListener(this);
        knapp2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(90,30));
        add(knapp2);

        pack();

        super.setVisible(true); 
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Ljudknappar();

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


        InputStream in;
        try
        {
        in = new FileInputStream( new File("my .wav file of choice"));  

        AudioStream Ljud = new AudioStream(in);

         Object src = e.getSource();

          if (src == knapp) 
          {
              AudioPlayer.player.start(Ljud);
          }

          if (src == knapp2) 
          {
              AudioPlayer.player.stop(Ljud);
          }
        }

        catch(Exception error)
        { 
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Something went wrong :("); 
        }

    }

}
```

Also, if you know of a way to solve this and have a third button for pausing, that'd be great as well.

I want to be able to start/stop the audio using without having to download JLayer or similar software. Only basic imports.

I am grateful for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not simply **not** keep making a new AudioStream in the actionPerformed, only create one when one doesn't already exist and is playing, and make `Ljud` a non-static field in your class? This way the stop button can stop it.